# Any suggestion for me to buffer data in my web server which runs in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, buffer

I have considered about it for a long time.

I think I can't use all the API/PHP extension (e.g. memcache, APC, Xcache) that need to install something in my remote Linux server, as my web host server is a shared server, what I just can do is to place files/scripts in the httpdocs folder.

Is there any suggestion for me that can let me programmatically use caching and access the memory?

Actually what I aim at is to find a "place" to save some data, that can be accessed in higher speed than entering the DB to fetch data, and also to reduce the loading to DB.
That means, it is not a must to use memory, if someone can give any other effective suggestions. e.g. will using text file be a good choice?(actually I am just guessing it)

The PHP version of mine is 5.2.17. And I am using MySQL DB.

Hope someone can give me suggestions

Comment: Is there any API that didn't require "installing" and just need to include the API php codes folder in my web httpdocs for me to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flat files will always be the EASIEST way for caching, but it will be slower than accessing data directly from memory. You can use MySQL tables that are stored in memory. you need to change the engine used by tables to memory. NOTE that this will work only if your db is on the same server as web server.

Set up an in memory table with two columns key and value. variable name will be a key and its contents are values. if you need to cache array, objects then serialize the data before storing it.

If you need to limit the size of in memory table add one more column hitCount. for each read increase the count by one. while inserting new row, check for max number of rows and if its reached a limit delete the row with lowest hitCount.

To check which one is faster (file caching or in memory cache) use following code

```
<?php 
function getTime() 
{ 
    $a = explode (' ',microtime()); 
    return(double) $a[0] + $a[1]; 
} 
?>

<?php 
    $Start = getTime();
    //Data fetching tasks comes here
    $end = getTime(); 
    echo "time taken = ".number_format(($End - $Start),2)."seconds";
?>
```

If possible let us know how efficient it is... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could very easily just use flat text files as a cache if your DB queries are expensive. Just like you would use memcache with a key/value system, you can use filenames as keys and the context of the files as values.

Here's an example that caches the output of a single page in a file; you could adapt it to suit your needs: http://www.snipe.net/2009/03/quick-and-dirty-php-caching/

Comment: Thanks. Is accessing files quicker than accessing DB?

Comment: As what you suggested, will it be a matter if there are too much files? as you proposed that we can have each file for one key.

Comment: You'd have to have quite a lot of files to have "too many". As for speed, it depends on how fast your queries are. If your queries are fast, then you might not need a cache at all; if they're slow, then a file cache will probably be faster.

Answer (score 1):

Flat file is the easiest way to cache business logic, queries etc on a shared server.

To cache any DB requests your best bet is to fetch the results, [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) them and store them  in a file with a possible expiry date (if required). When you need to fetch those results again just pull in the file and [unserialize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) the previously serialized data.

Also if the data is user based cookies and sessions will work too, for as long as the user stays on the application at least. If your pulling a lot of data it would still be better to go with the first option and just save the files based on a user/session id.

Comment: Also to add, queries are typically always the biggest bottleneck in any php application from my experience. Flat files are easy on memory to load in as aposed to sending a request to the DB. Benchmarking the application will allow you to get an idea where the bottlenecks are.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the size of data to cahce.
Based on the restriction of your server environment:

- Use flat file( or maybe sqlite db) to cache your data for large data set (e.g., user 
  preference, user activity logs.)
- Use share memory to cache your data for the smaller data set (e.g., system counter, system 
  status.)

Hope this helps.